# How to use SSH-1 RSA public/private key pair I generated in PuTTY

Tags: rsa, putty

I want to upload both the public and private key files to my Express back-end to use for testing/learning purposes in user authentication in an app under development (i.e., development environment). I plan to use `express-jwt`, `jwks-rsa` and `jsonwebtoken` to create/sign a jwt in my Express back-end, and then to validate the jwt returned on each subsequent HTTP request from front-end to back-end. I.e., I'm just trying to implement a plain-vanilla user authentication protocol.

When I open the public key file in Notepad++, it appears the contents are in Decimal Base. It shows

`2048 37 19249 . . . rsa-key-20191018`

When I open the private key file in Notepad++, I see:

`SSH PRIVATE KEY FILE FORMAT 1.1
         ˜|{Éî”áÛaèn7 . . .`
(basically a whole bunch of gibberish)

I seem to recall reading that I need to convert these to Base64URL, but I don't even know how to start doing that.

How do I convert these files into a format my app can use to generate and validate `JWT` tokens for user authentication?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to use `express-jwt`, `jwks-rsa` and `jsonwebtoken` to create/sign a `jwt` in my Express back-end, and then to validate the `jwt`returned on each subsequent `HTTP request` from front-end to back-end. I.e., I'm just trying to implement a plain-vanilla user authentication protocol. If further information needed, please let me know . . . as I'm a beginner I don't know exactly which type of information you might need to help me figure this out.